# TFS 2012 Work Item State Transition for multiple groups

Tags: templates, process, tfs, customization

Right at the moment i'm customizing a process template and there should be an transition for a work item from State A to B, which should be restricted to multiple tfs groups, to be presice it should be two groups.

Are there any ways to do this in the process template?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337653%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

As far as i know the FOR-Attribute can only be used for a single TFS group.
The only workaround i'd know is to assign the group as a member of the other.

Regards,
Marcel

Comment: You answered your own question correctly. As of TFS 2018, there is still no way to specify multiple groups in the FOR or NOT attributes of a state transition.

Answer (score 1):

The trick I use is to create a TFS group specific for the FOR clause and add the TFS or Windows groups you need as members.
It is also possible to script it using the TFSSecurity command.

Comment: That's what I've assumed.
Alright. Thx for your response.

Comment: This is still accurate as of TFS 2018; there is no way to specify multiple groups in the FOR or NOT attributes of a state transition. I found at least one case of the feature being requested and subsequently denied.